# How to optimise this stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have the stored procedure below and I am having two issues with it

1. It is running very slowly, and
2. It is returning a blank result set

The idea for the stored procedure is to do a sequence check to find if any account numbers have not been assigned.

Step 1 loops through all the branches and builds up the tempdetails table.

After that it creates the list of all the numbers that have been used and uses that to delete everything that exists to leave a list of those accountnumbers that do not exist,

But een though I know there are missing account numbers, aside from the exceptionally long tun time it is returning a blank result set. 
Anyone have any ideas what is going wrong with it?

Thanks

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PracticeFindMissingSequenceDetail]
      @pracId VARCHAR(128),
      @Prefix VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @TempDetails TABLE (SequenceCheck VARCHAR(24), 
                                Prefix VARCHAR(4), 
                                BranchName VARCHAR(256), 
                                RisStatus VARCHAR(256), 
                                Rislink VARCHAR(256)
                               );
    DECLARE @Branchlist TABLE (BranchId INTEGER, 
                               BranchName VARCHAR(256), 
                               BranchPrefix VARCHAR(4), 
                               PrefixLength INT, 
                               SequenceLength INT
                              );
    DECLARE @TempPatNo TABLE (Patno VARCHAR(24));

    DECLARE @BranchName  VARCHAR(256),
            @BranchPrefix VARCHAR(256),
            @PrefixLength INT,
            @BranchId INT,
            @SequenceLength INT,
            @rangestart INTEGER,
            @rangeend INTEGER,
            @rangenow INTEGER,
            @startDate DATETIME,
            @Patno VARCHAR(128),
            @FormatZeroes VARCHAR(3),
            @CurrentLength INT,
            @RangeString VARCHAR(256);

    INSERT INTO @Branchlist (BranchId, BranchName, BranchPrefix, PrefixLength, SequenceLength)
        SELECT 
            b.id, b.name, b.prefix, PrefixLength, SequenceLength
        FROM
            Branch b
        INNER JOIN 
            Practice pr ON pr.id = b.practiceid
        INNER JOIN 
            [Sequence] s ON s.id = b.id
        WHERE 
            pr.APIKey = @pracID
            AND b.inactive = 0
            AND b.prefix = @Prefix

        /* insert values for each branch into table*/
        DECLARE BranchPointer CURSOR FOR
            SELECT BranchID FROM @Branchlist

        OPEN BranchPointer

        FETCH NEXT FROM BranchPointer INTO @BranchId

        WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
        BEGIN
            SELECT @BranchPrefix = (SELECT BranchPrefix 
                                    FROM @Branchlist
                                    WHERE BranchId = @BranchId)
            SELECT @PrefixLength = (SELECT PrefixLength
                                    FROM @Branchlist
                                    WHERE BranchId = @BranchId)
            SELECT @SequenceLength = (SELEct SequenceLength
                                      FROM @Branchlist
                                      WHERE BranchId = @BranchId)

        /* Set the starting date from the sequence */
        SELECT @startDate = (SELECT MIN(MinimumSequenceDate)
                             FROM [Sequence] s
                             WHERE s.id = @BranchId)

        /*get the earliest number in the sequence from the startdate*/                                               
        SELECT @rangestart = (SELECT MIN(SUBSTRING(v.bookingnumber, 3, LEN(bookingnumber))) 
                              FROM Visit v
                              INNER join Branch b ON b.id = v.branchid
                              INNER join Practice pr ON pr.id = b.practiceid
                              WHERE pr.APIKey = @pracId
                                AND LEFT(v.bookingnumber, 2) = @Prefix
                                AND v.date >= @startDate
                                AND v.branchid = @BranchId);

        /*get the latest number in the sequence from the startdate*/
        SELECT @rangeend = (SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING(v.bookingnumber, 3, LEN(bookingnumber))) 
                            FROM Visit v
                            INNER JOIN Branch b ON b.id = v.branchid
                            INNER JOIN Practice pr ON pr.id = b.practiceid
                            WHERE pr.APIKey = @pracId
                              AND LEFT(v.bookingnumber, 2) = @Prefix
                              AND v.date >= @startDate
                              AND v.branchid = @BranchId);

        SET @RangeNow = @rangestart

        WHILE @rangenow < @rangeend
        BEGIN
            /*check if leading zeroes are needed in the number and add them if needed*/
            SET @RangeString = CAST(@RangeNow AS VARCHAR(256))
            SET @CurrentLength = LEN(@rangenow)

            IF @prefixlength + @currentlength < @SequenceLength
                WHILE @CurrentLength + @PrefixLength < @SequenceLength
                BEGIN
                    SET @RangeString = '0' + @RangeString;
                    SET @currentlength = LEN(@RangeString);
                END;

            /*Insert full sequence into temporary table*/
            INSERT INTO @TempDetails (SequenceCheck, Prefix, BranchName)
                SELECT @Prefix + @RangeString, @Prefix, @BranchName

            SET @rangenow =@rangenow+1
        END;

        FETCH NEXT FROM BranchPointer INTO @BranchName
    END

    CLOSE BranchPointer
    DEALLOCATE BranchPointer    

    /*delete existing sequence numbers from table*/
    INSERT INTO @TempPatNo (PatNo)
        SELECT BookingNumber 
        FROM Visit v1 
        INNER JOIN Branch b1 ON b1.id = v1.branchid
        INNER JOIN Practice pr1 ON pr1.id = b1.practiceid
        WHERE pr1.APIKey = @pracId

    DELETE @TempDetails
    WHERE sequencecheck IN (SELECT patNo FROM @TempPatNo)

    /*Insert the status and link for error messages*/
    UPDATE @tempDetails
    SET RisStatus = (SELECT Status 
                     FROM RISErrors r
                     INNER JOIN Practice pr ON pr.id = r.PracticeId
                     WHERE pr.APIKey = @pracId
                       AND VisitNumber = SequenceCheck
                       AND r.id = (SELECT MAX(r1.id) 
                                   FROM RISErrors r1
                                   INNER JOIN Practice pr1 ON pr1.id = r1.PracticeId
                                   WHERE pr1.APIKey = @pracId
                                     AND VisitNumber = SequenceCheck)),
        RisLink = 'http://billing.cryanic.co.za/Clinton/RISErrors?searchquery=' + SequenceCheck

    /*return missing numbers into sequence control callong procedure*/
    SELECT DISTINCT SequenceCheck, RisStatus, Rislink 
    FROM @TempDetails
END
```

Comment: #1 - how much data are you dealing with? #2 - dealing with data in sets vs using cursors will almost always be faster. #3 - specify your sql version so the answer can use the best possible solution for your version. #4 - indexing may fix some issues. #5 - you may be able to set up a mock db and data, for us to play around with, if still have issues: http://sqlfiddle.com/  (don't use real data!)

Comment: There can be lots of business rules we don't know about, so it's hard to say what is wrong. Perhaps, very first steps lead to wrong path - so, where we would go? )

Comment: Trivial change: `select @BranchPrefix = BranchPrefix, @PrefixLength = PrefixLength, @SequenceLength = SequenceLength from @BranchList where BranchId = @BranchId;`. In general, using `select ( select ( select ( ...` doesn't help when only one `select` is needed.

Comment: Optimization is something that depend on your database structure, your data, and a lot of parameters. Optimize a query directly involves optimize the table structure (choosing the right indexes for example). A query that fit best for one database can be the worse for another database! Therefore, if you want to speak about optimization then you should give us the tools to reproduce a scenario as close as possible to yours. `(I must split the response in this poor interface... will continue in next comment)`

Comment: Please post queries to create the relevant table(s) including all the indexes, constraints and so on. Please provide queries to insert some fake sample data. And most important please provide your real Execution Plan (the XML version and not an image).

Comment: First Thing without an optimization: In the second `FETCH NEXT FROM BranchPointer` you must also fetch `INTO @BranchId`.

Answer (score 0):

After reading your procedure, I made some assumptions:

1. there is a one-to-one relationsship between *sequence* and *branch*
2. the *visits* are the details of a *sequence*
3. the *BranchName* and *BranchPrefix* aren't needed.

I recommend to not do lookups by *BranchID* but instead retrieve the values from the cursor query. The table *BranchList* isn't needed, you can base the cursor on the query directly. Also, the *TempPatNo* table can be avoided.

Here's what I have come up with:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[PracticeFindMissingSequenceDetail]
  @pracId VARCHAR(128),
  @Prefix VARCHAR(256)
AS
BEGIN
  DECLARE @TempDetails TABLE (
    BranchID INT,
    SequenceCheck VARCHAR(24),
    RisStatus VARCHAR(256),
    Rislink VARCHAR(256)
  );

  DECLARE
    @PrefixLength INT,
    @BranchId INT,
    @SequenceLength INT,
    @rangestart INTEGER,
    @rangeend INTEGER,
    @rangenow INTEGER,
    @startDate DATETIME;

    /* insert values for each branch into table*/
    DECLARE BranchPointer CURSOR FOR
      SELECT b.id, PrefixLength, SequenceLength, s.MinimumSequenceDate
      FROM Branch b
        INNER JOIN Practice pr ON pr.id = b.practiceid
        INNER JOIN [Sequence] s ON s.id = b.id
      WHERE pr.APIKey = @pracID 
        AND b.prefix = @Prefix
        AND b.inactive = 0 

    OPEN BranchPointer
    FETCH NEXT FROM BranchPointer INTO @BranchId, @PrefixLength, @SequenceLength, @startDate

    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
    BEGIN

      /*get the earliest and latest number in the sequence from the startdate*/                                               
      SELECT 
        @rangestart = MIN(SUBSTRING(v.bookingnumber, 3, LEN(v.bookingnumber))),
        @rangeend = MAX(SUBSTRING(v.bookingnumber, 3, LEN(v.bookingnumber)))
      FROM Visit v
      WHERE v.branchid = @BranchId
        AND v.date >= @startDate
        AND LEFT(v.bookingnumber, 2) = @Prefix;

      SET @RangeNow = @rangestart

      WHILE @rangenow < @rangeend
      BEGIN

            /*Insert full sequence into temporary table*/
        INSERT INTO @TempDetails (BranchID, SequenceCheck)
          SELECT @BranchId,
            @Prefix + REPLICATE('0', @SequenceLength-@PrefixLength-LEN(@rangenow)) + CAST(@RangeNow AS VARCHAR(256));

        SET @rangenow =@rangenow+1
      END;

      FETCH NEXT FROM BranchPointer INTO @BranchId, @PrefixLength, @SequenceLength, @startDate
    END

    CLOSE BranchPointer
    DEALLOCATE BranchPointer    

    /*delete existing sequence numbers from table*/
    DELETE FROM @TempDetails
    FROM @TempDetails t
      INNER JOIN Visit v ON t.BranchID = v.branchid
    WHERE t.SequenceCheck = v.BookingNumber

    /*Insert the status and link for error messages*/
    UPDATE @tempDetails
    SET RisStatus = (SELECT Status 
                     FROM RISErrors r
                       INNER JOIN Practice pr ON pr.id = r.PracticeId
                     WHERE pr.APIKey = @pracId
                       AND VisitNumber = SequenceCheck
                       AND r.id = (SELECT MAX(r1.id) 
                                   FROM RISErrors r1
                                     INNER JOIN Practice pr1 ON pr1.id = r1.PracticeId
                                   WHERE pr1.APIKey = @pracId
                                     AND VisitNumber = SequenceCheck)),
        RisLink = 'http://billing.cryanic.co.za/Clinton/RISErrors?searchquery=' + SequenceCheck

    /*return missing numbers into sequence control callong procedure*/
    SELECT DISTINCT SequenceCheck, RisStatus, Rislink 
    FROM @TempDetails
END
```